# Redirecting to next url with additional parameters using LoginView

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I have a detail page `/spaces/<int:pk>/` where an unauthenticated user can enter form data.

Upon submitting the form, this data is appended to the url like:

`/spaces/<int:pk>/?product_id=1&start_date=2022-12-23&duration=1`

The user is then prompted to login or register to continue. Upon clicking login, the detail page url is appended as a next parameter to the login url.

`/login/?next=/spaces/1/?product_id=14&start_date=2022-12-23&duration=1`

However, after logging in and redirecting back to the detail page, the url looks like:

`/spaces/1/?product_id=14`

This is because the url is split with `&` when parsed, so the `start_date` and `duration` are considered as separate parameters.

The only solution i can think of is to override `LoginView.get_redirect_url` and append each parameter from self.request.GET separately, but I'm not sure that is the best approach here.

My goal is to preserve the initial input data so that the user does not have to input it again after logging in and landing back on the space detail page. For conversion reasons, I do not want to force the user to login before entering the initial form data.

EDIT:
I am using javascript set the `href` on the Login and Register buttons:

```
const onClick = () => {
  let prodId = document.getElementById('productId').value;
  let startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
  let duration = document.getElementById('duration').value;
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  url.searchParams.set('product_id', prodId);
  url.searchParams.set('start_date', startDate);
  url.searchParams.set('duration', duration);
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, url);

  const queryString = window.location.search;
  document.getElementById('login').href = `{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}${queryString}`;
  document.getElementById('register').href = `{% url 'register' %}?next={{request.path}}${queryString}`
}
```

Comment: Looks like the `next` does not properly encode the querystring. Did you define a custom `@login_required` or `LoginRequiredMixin`?

Comment: I do not want to enforce login_required on the space detail page. The goal is to enable an unauthenticated user to enter data first, before asking him to login.

Comment: But how do you redirect with `?next=...`. Where did you implement that logic?

Comment: I see what you mean now. I am using Javascript for that. please have a look at my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to urlencode the querystring (and the path), properly, so:

```
const queryString = encodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
document.getElementById('login').href = `{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }}${queryString}`;
document.getElementById('register').href = `{% url 'register' %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }}${queryString}
```

Comment: top, bedankt Willem! learnt something new.